# Can't run pgadmin4, no module named flask error

Tags: ubuntu, flask, pgadmin-4

I have search similar error in StackOverflow, but its different than mine. I tried to install pgadmin4 on ubuntu with virtualenv, everything went fine until I tried to run it with following command :

```
cd pgadmin4
source bin/activate
sudo python ~/pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

It raises an error saying :

```
ImportError: No module named flask
```

I have flash installed. Running pip show flask under the virtualenv will show :

```
Name: Flask
Version: 0.11.1
Summary: A microframework based on Werkzeug, Jinja2 and good intentions
Home-page: http://github.com/pallets/flask/
Author: Armin Ronacher
Author-email: armin.ronacher@active-4.com
License: BSD
Location: /home/myname/pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: itsdangerous, click, Werkzeug, Jinja2
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Thank you,

Comment: Same problem. Nope, that's not why; pip freeze on my venv certainly includes flask.

Answer (score 11):

Provide proper permission to directory by following command,

```
sudo mkdir "/var/log/pgadmin" 
sudo chmod a+wrx "/var/log/pgadmin" 

sudo mkdir "/var/lib/pgadmin" 
sudo chmod a+wrx "/var/lib/pgadmin"
```

And then run the pgAdmin4 **without** `sudo`

```
cd pgadmin4
source bin/activate
python ~/pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

Comment: I wasn't sure what directory to run this code so I did it from the virtual environment root.  (.pgadmin4) vagrant@myBox:~/.pgadmin4$.  This works as n33ma suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was somehow it tries to get flask on my system rather than on virtualenv. So i just installed flask on my system, and it works.

Comment: That's the wrong way to do it, you already have flask in your virtual environment.

Comment: @MurtuzaZ except it will not work when the venv is shipped by pgadmin repo and it is using the wrong python version. For example my python is 3.10 and venv comes with 3.9 so nothing is there, unless I rebuild the venv.